# TM symbol not displaying correctly on redirected URL

Tags: .net, redirect, character-encoding, url-rewriting

I have a url that redirects to a page on my main site. For some reason, when I access through the rewritten URL, a TM symbol is showing up as â¢, but when I access through the main site, it shows up correctly.

The urls are http://waterlessmilkwarmer.com/ and http://www.medelabreastfeedingus.com/milk-warmer so you can see what's happening. They are both looking at exactly the same page (the first url redirects to the second). Look at the page title ("Introducing the first and only...") to see what's happening.

The site is running on .NET and that page title is being stored and pulled directly from the database. There are HTMLEncode calls on it, but when I removed them and just displayed it directly from the database, it still did the same thing.

I'm guessing the redirected url has something to do with this, but I don't know what. Has anyone seen this before and know what could be happening?

Comment: how exactly do you do the redirect? it is not a http 3xx redirect, as the response status code from http://waterlessmilkwarmer.com/ is 200. seems to me that the TM symbol (hex E2 84 A2 in utf-8, as properly at http://www.medelabreastfeedingus.com/milk-warmer) gets double encoded: at http://waterlessmilkwarmer.com/ , it is hex C3 A2 C2 84 C2 A2 .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turns out that there was an issue with the TM symbol in the database. Once it was removed and added back in, everything seems to work fine.

Answer (score 3):

If you look at the page properties in Firefox, the rendering mode of the two pages is different.

medelabreastfeedingus.com -> Standards compliance mode
waterlessmilkwarmer.com -> Quirks mode

I *suspect* that this is what is causing the difference. The different rendering mode is  possibly triggered by the `<base href="http://www.medelabreastfeedingus.com/" />` tag that is rendered outside of the `<html>` tags, and also before the `<DOCTYPE>` tag - my HTML validator says that the doctype tag cannot appear after other elements.

You could try using the HTML entity instead (`&trade;` will render as ™) - that should work in both modes.

Comment: I suspect the faulty use of `<base>` (should be in the `<head>`, not at the start of the document) may also cause the browser to ignore the `<meta>` where the character set is declared. IMO better to fix this than resort to HTML entity references (after all there may be other Unicode characters you want to use).

Comment: Yes, I'd agree. I validated the redirected page and there were several other problems that looked like they were caused by the `base` tag being in the wrong place.

Answer (score 1):

I don't know why that's happening (definitely weird) but I did notice that you're using the actual character instead of the HTML encoding version `&trade;` which would work regardless.